# How do you sort alphabetical without case sensitive

Tags: javascript

How do i make this alpha sort not case sensitive? I understand that you should use to toLowerCase but I don't know how.

```
sort_alpha: function(a,b) {
    if (a[0]==b[0]) return 0;
    if (a[0]<b[0]) return -1;
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: if (a[0].toLowerCase()<b[0].toLowerCase()){ return -1; }

Comment: Answers go in answers, not in comments.

Comment: i'm not putting my brand on a over-asked low-level question to catch drive-by downvotes, but i don't mind making minimal effort helping the dude. code-only answers suck anyway, and this isn't even a full working code...

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn a and b into lower case

```
var lower_a = a.toLowerCase();
var lower_b = b.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: why duplicate each value twice into a var? doing so only increases ram and cpu costs while lowering stability...

Comment: I agree, ram is a critical issue nowadays. I just wrote that way to be more clear. Now if he wants to create two more variables it's up to him.